# Python PyQt4 creating pdf from qlayout

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt, pyqt4, qlayout

I am developing an app using PyQt4. And I would like to have an option to print the main widget to a pdf document. I have a custom qlayout for the main widget and I want to create a pdf document with that qlayout. I read a lot about pyqt qprinter, but I'm not sure that's what I want.

Could anyone suggest how I could create a pdf with a qlayout full of qwidgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [QPixmap.grabWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#grabWidget) to render the widget to a pixmap, then paint that on a [QPrinter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprinter.html) which can then convert it to a pdf:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.text.setText(open(__file__).read())
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.edit.setText('/tmp/test.pdf')
        self.buttonSave = QtGui.QPushButton('Save', self)
        self.buttonSave.clicked.connect(self.handleSave)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.text, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonSave, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    def handleSave(self):
        printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
        printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPrinter.A6)
        printer.setColorMode(QtGui.QPrinter.Color)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName(self.edit.text())
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(self).scaled(
            printer.pageRect(QtGui.QPrinter.DevicePixel).size().toSize(),
            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)
        painter.end()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 640, 640)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDIT**:

If the `QPainter` part won't work for some reason on your setup, you could try the alternative save method below:

```
    def handleSave(self):
        printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
        printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPrinter.A9)
        printer.setColorMode(QtGui.QPrinter.Color)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName(self.edit.text())
        self.render(printer)
```

Or another alternative would be to use a `QTextDocument`:

```
    def handleSave(self):
        printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
        printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPrinter.A5)
        printer.setResolution(200)
        printer.setColorMode(QtGui.QPrinter.Color)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName(self.edit.text())
        size = printer.pageRect(QtGui.QPrinter.DevicePixel).size()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(self).scaled(
            size.toSize(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        data = QtCore.QByteArray()
        buffer = QtCore.QBuffer(data)
        pixmap.save(buffer, 'PNG')
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        document.setPageSize(size)
        document.setHtml('<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s"/>' %
                         bytes(data.toBase64()).decode('ascii'))
        document.print_(printer)
```

Comment: When I run you're code it gives me two errors: `QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted` and `QPainter::begin(): Returned false` do you know how to fix that?

Comment: And when do I write the qlayout to the pdf?

Comment: @CheynShmuel. The code works perfectly for me. Did you edit it in some way? It makes no sense to print a layout because it is not visible. You have to print the widget that the layout is set on.

Comment: No, I copy-pasted your code, and the GUI shows up as expected, but the save button doesn't work.

Comment: @CheynShmuel. What platform are you on? What versions of PyQt4 and Qt4 are you using?

Comment: @CheynShmuel. I added some alternative solutions which might work better for you.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 professional. I am using pyqt4. what do you mean which version of pyqt4? I tried the two solutions you added but they both give me this error: 
`QPainter::begin(): Returned false` and the first alternative gives me this error:

`QPainter::worldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints`
I don't think you need to offer a whole nother solution, I think it's just something small. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, @ekhumoro, I got the third option to work in my program. BUT, it literally prints the way the widget looks with the gray background, and the scrollbar(my widget is a qscrollarea). I don't want that. I want it to only take the layout, not the widget, and adjust it to the size of the a4 paper, and span multiple pages if needed. BTW the layout is the flowlayout that you gave me in my other question.

Comment: @CheynShmuel. As I said before: you need to print the *specific widget* that the layout is set on: i.e. `grabWidget(scrollarea.widget())`. PS: remember my advice about using html rather than widgets? If you did that, you wouldn't be having these sorts of problems (and there will be many more to come). PDF is a **document** format: so printing a multi-page html document in a `QTextBrowser` would be no problem at all.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to move to html